# Achieving a gui similiar to the picture?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

[image]

My plan is to get a similiar output, but for some reason, I am only getting the south panel...

My logic is to have 1 Main panel with North Center South.

- In the North I will puth the Jlabel and Textfield and align it to the right.
- In the Center I wil leave it empty
- In the South I will Add a BoxLayout y-axis in the first row another panel with centered boxlayout

Another BoxLayout in the second row of the South BoxLayour row, I will add another Boxlayout and align it to the left.

Here is my code:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override


        public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(new Dimension(500,600));
            JPanel MainPanel = new JPanel();
frame.add(MainPanel);

            JPanel NorthPanel = new JPanel(); //upper panel to add boxx layout and inside it 2 panls
            JPanel ToPanel = new JPanel(); //inside north
            JPanel SubjectPanel = new JPanel(); //inside north

            NorthPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(NorthPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            MainPanel.add(NorthPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


            JLabel SubjectLabel = new JLabel("Subject");  SubjectLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
            JTextField  SubjectTextField = new JTextField(20); SubjectTextField.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);

            JLabel ToLabel = new JLabel("To");  ToLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
            JTextField  ToTextField = new JTextField(20); ToTextField.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
            ToPanel.add(ToLabel);
            ToPanel.add(ToTextField);

            ToPanel.add(SubjectLabel);
            ToPanel.add(SubjectTextField);
            NorthPanel.add(ToPanel);

            JPanel CenterPanel = new JPanel(); //Center panel  blank
            MainPanel.add(CenterPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            ///
            JPanel SouthPanel = new JPanel();
            NorthPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(NorthPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

            JPanel FontPanels = new JPanel();
            FontPanels.setLayout(new BoxLayout(FontPanels, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
            FontPanels.add(new JButton("Bold"));
            FontPanels.add(new JButton("Italic"));
            FontPanels.add(new JButton("Underlined"));
            FontPanels.add(new JButton("Undo"));
            FontPanels.add(new JButton("Redo"));
            FontPanels.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

            JPanel OptionPanel = new JPanel();
            OptionPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(OptionPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

            FontPanels.setLayout(new BoxLayout(FontPanels, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

            OptionPanel.add(new JButton("Send"));

            OptionPanel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
                    SouthPanel.add(FontPanels);
                    SouthPanel.add(OptionPanel);

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }

    });

    }
```

Comment: looks to me like you forgot to add your components to your frame.

Comment: The output is still different even after adding it to the frame

Comment: (1-) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Your code is difficult to read because all your variables are highlighted like class names. If you want people to help make sure the code is easy to read.

Comment: 1) *"Achieving a gui similiar to the picture?"* Why? It's awful. The `To` field should be shorter than the `Subject` field & both fields and labels need some white space. The text area (where is that created & added, BTW?) needs a scroll pane. The next row of buttons is fine, but the last row also needs white space. 2) Instead of `frame.setSize(new Dimension(500,600));` (which is no better than a guess) change `frame.setVisible(true);` to `frame.pack(); frame.setVisible(true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added anything to the JFrame - so naturally it is displaying a blank JFrame.

For each component to appear, you'll need to do `frame.add(component);`

I leave the layout manager of the frame up to you.

Comment: Cant i just add "  frame.add(MainPanel); " since i am adding later everything to it

Comment: In theory you are correct - the only way to know for sure is for you to test it. It is best to start small with Swing and add components one at a time.